# How to save changes using UPDATE made to custom sqlite database Android

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-update

I have a sqlite database that I have in the access folder. I read to it and update fields fine in my app. But when I close the app down and start it again, the changes made to the fields are the original values.

It seems the database is overwritten when when the app starts up. Is there a way to save the data, and open the new database? What am I doing wrong here?

```
//    My understanding is:
//    if no-Database created (first use)
//       CreateDatabase()
//    openDatabase() (2nd use and more) and this is not updated


public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


public static DataBaseHelper getInstance(Context context)
    {
        if(mDBHelper == null)
        {
            mDBHelper = new DataBaseHelper(context);
        }
        return mDBHelper;
    }


    public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {

        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        this.myContext = context;
        //String packageName = context.getPackageName();
        if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17){
            DB_PATH = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";
        }else{
            DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";

        }
    }




    public void createDataBase() throws IOException {

        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if(dbExist){
//do nothing - database already exist

        }else{

//By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
//of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
            this.getReadableDatabase();

            try {

                copyDataBase();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                Log.e("CreateDatabase", "Error copying database " + e.toString());
                throw new Error("Error copying database");

            }
        }

    }


    private boolean checkDataBase(){

        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try{
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        }catch(SQLiteException e){
        Log.v("CheckDatabase", "Database does not exist yet");
//database does't exist yet.

        }

        if(checkDB != null){

            checkDB.close();

        }

        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }


    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

//Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = null;
        try {
            myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

// Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

//Open the empty db as the output stream

        OutputStream myOutput = null;
        try {
            myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

//transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

//Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {

//Open the database

        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        try {
            myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);//OPEN_READONLY);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {

        if(myDataBase != null)
            myDataBase.close();

        super.close();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }


public int updateWeight(int id)
    {
        W w = getW(id);
        int newWeight = w.getWeight()+1;

        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(col_one, newWeight);
        args.put(col_two, word.getTwo());
        args.put(col_three, word.getThree());



        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        Log.v("update Weight", "Weight = " + newWeight);
        return db.update(TABLE_NAME, args, col_id + "=?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
    }
}
```

usage:
in onCreate

```
private DataBaseHelper myDbHelper;


@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);


        try {

            myDbHelper.createDataBase();

        } catch (IOException ioe) {

            throw new Error("Unable to create database");

        }

        try {

            myDbHelper.openDataBase();

        }catch(SQLException sqle){

            throw sqle;

        }

_gotit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                myDbHelper.updateWeight(whereAmI);

            }
        });

}
```

Comment: `It seems the database is overwritten when when the app starts up` so why you didn't check this first ... post some log statement in right place and check if it appear in logcat ... maybe your update code is not not working ...

Comment: The update function works fine, the database seems to not stay. CheckDatabase() logs Database does not exist yet when starting. which means it isnt saved? So what do I need to do?

Comment: You wont believe it, but I had to change READ_ONLY to NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed

```
checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.READ_ONLY);
```

in CheckDataBase, to:

```
checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);
```

This works now. Thank you.